Formatting nullable DateTime
This is my function:
private static string strTimeStampMsg(string strMsg, DateTime? dtTimestamp = null) {
    if (strMsg == null || strMsg.Length == 0) {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string strDateTime;
    if (dtTimestamp != null) {
        strDateTime = dtTimestamp.ToString(CSTR.dtFormat);
    } else {
        strDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(CSTR.dtFormat);
    }
    return strDateTime + "> " + strMsg;
}

CSTR.dtFormat is defined in a DLL:
public const string dtFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";

Today I've added the optional, the problem is the line:
strDateTime = dtTimestamp.ToString(CSTR.dtFormat);

Has a red underline under ToString, why and how do I resolve whilst being able to format using the required format?

As an aside, I'd strongly recommend starting to follow .NET naming conventions, but that's a rather different matter.

@JonSkeet, .NET naming conventions are not as useful as the ones I use and I've been writing software for a very long time.

Each to their own - but I hope you're not forcing that inconsistency (between calling pretty much every other .NET library on the planet and calling into your own code) on a team. The .NET ecosystem is pretty good at being consistent on this.

I'd also suggest that when writing Stack Overflow questions and answers, it's worth considering that the audience of that code is not you, but the wider community. So unless you think that your convention is so superior to the widely-adopted one that readers will find it easier to adjust to your convention than to follow code written in the one they're familiar with, it's better to violate your own conventions for the audience's sake. Basically, there's a difference between "what you want to be in your own codebase" and "code on Stack Overflow for public consumption".

This question is similar to: How can I format a nullable DateTime with ToString()?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.


Has a red underline under ToString, why and how do I resolve whilst being able to format using the required format?

Well, you could use dtTimestamp.Value.ToString(...) so that you're trying to call DateTime.ToString instead of Nullable<DateTime>.ToString().
Note that this isn't really about the value coming from an optional parameter - it's about it being a Nullable<DateTime> rather than a DateTime. If you'd obtained that Nullable<DateTime> value from anywhere else, without using optional parameters, you'd still face the same issue.
But there's a better solution which avoid code duplication:
string strDateTime = (dtTimestamp ?? DateTime.Now).ToString(CSTR.dtFormat);

That uses the null-coalescing operator - ?? - to effectively use DateTime.Now as a default.
I view this as cleaner code than, because it makes it clear that the only difference between explicitly providing the DateTime value and using the default value is in which part is formatted - you do the same operation with the result either way. In your current code, both branches perform an operation on the chosen DateTime, and while they're the same right now it would be easy for them to end up inconsistent.
